# systemd file not pickuping environment values

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl, ubuntu-22.04, filebeat

Systemd file for filebeat doesn't pickup env variables and throw as below

```
ExecStart=/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -environment systemd $BEAT_LOG_OPTS $BEAT_CONFIG_OPTS $BEAT_PATH_OPTS (code=exited, status=2)
```

Below is my systemd for filebeat service

```
 [Unit]
Description=Filebeat sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
Documentation=https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]

Environment="BEAT_LOG_OPTS="
Environment="BEAT_CONFIG_OPTS=-c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml"
Environment="BEAT_PATH_OPTS=-path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat"
ExecStart=/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -environment systemd $BEAT_LOG_OPTS $BEAT_CONFIG_OPTS $BEAT_PATH_OPTS
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [filebeat documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/command-line-options.html), `-environment` is not used for specifying [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), but to specify the environment the Filebeat is running. Moreover, the `BEAT_PATH_OPTS` is available to filebeat process, ant not available to systemd, where you are trying to use with `$BEAT_LOG_OPTS`. The systemd service file is not a shell script. See [man systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) for details.

> -environment
>
> For logging purposes, specifies the environment that Filebeat is running in. This setting is used to select a default log
> output when no log output is configured. Supported values are:
> `systemd`, `container`, `macos_service`, and `windows_service`. If `systemd` or
> `container` is specified, Filebeat will log to stdout and stderr by
> default.

Answer (score 0):

Those values are not shell environment variables, but they may be read from the service unit's supplementary files from the "drop-in" directory. This is essentially a directory with a `.d` suffix, so if your service unit is `/etc/systemd/system/filebeat.service`, then you can have a file like `/etc/systemd/system/filebeat.service.d/filebeat.service.conf` (the filename can be anything, just keep the `.conf` extension).

Then your `filebeat.service.conf` would look like so:

```
[Service]
Environment="BEAT_LOG_OPTS="
Environment="BEAT_CONFIG_OPTS=-c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml"
Environment="BEAT_PATH_OPTS=-path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat"
```

So in a nutshell, you can move certain stuff out from the unit file, so it can remain unchanged, while the `.conf` files can be changed as needed.

And that's about it. systemd units aren't supposed to read environment variables. Those variables are limited to your shell.

Of course, you can set up all kinds of scripting to adjust these `.conf` files as needed, if you want, just be sure to call `systemctl daemon-reload` first. Until then, systemd will not re-read those values. Certain services uses other quirks that read variables from files in under `/etc/sysconfig` or other dirs, but the concept is the same. It's just a separation of the variables (i.e. the configuration) and the unit itself into different files.